# Matlab 2015a imcontour

Tags: matlab, contour

Matlab changed the behavior of `imcontour`, and I can't figure our how to get the individual xy of each contour in the image.

If in 2014a the code was:

```
[~,g] = imcontour(img,1);
pgons=arrayfun(@(x) get(x,'Vertices'),get(g,'children'),'uni',false);
```

In 2015, `g` is contour object and I cannot extract the individuals contours from it.

Comment: Doesn't the first output of `imcontour` give you the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is obtained by either :

```
[contourMat,g] = imcontour(img,1);
```

where contourMap is what you are looking for or else

```
g.ContourMatrix
```